# A weird Bug! Ubuntu keyboard and terminal, need guidance

Tags: 14.04, command-line, keyboard, bug-reporting

Today I observed a very strange behavior on my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. While my keyboard is fully functional on gedit editor and some other applications, when I am in Terminal, Google Chrome, or software package manager, Ubuntu acts strangely.
In Google Chrome, some part of the text I am typing automatically disappear from a search box, for example, "problem with my keyboard in Ubuntu" is typed and I see it, then, suddenly "problem with my" part deletes and remains only in ubuntu!

In Terminal, I can type something, but the characters changes, for example, s changes to j and some other disappear as I am typing. Accordingly, every password I enter for root mode is wrong due to this problem!

On software package, when I try to upgrade, as soon as the password prompt pops up, and I press a key, the program disappears totally and closes!

Would you please help me out how to track the source of this problem? I have my OS for two years now and reinstallation is not an option!

Thank you.

Comment: I can copy and paste from gedit though.

Comment: Sounds like a hardware error to me, either the keyboard generating spurious signals, or more likely a RAM failure or similar. Anything suspicious (e.g. lots of segfaults) in the output of `dmesg`? Or maybe just some key component (e.g. kernel, Xorg) went haywire and a reboot fixes it.

Comment: The problem only exists in these three applications though. Editors or the word processors just work fine. Reboot didn't work. No segfault in dmesg!